# Can create and save Word files in Python, but cannot print them

Tags: python, printing

I have made a Client Report Generator - by entering info into the various fields, the app will generate a Word file, save it, print it, and then clear the entry fields to be used for the next report. I have gotten everything working, except for the printing. I have tried multiple solutions, and the one that seems to have the most promise is included in my code. If anyone can figure out what is going on, I would greatly appreciate it. File locations are not final, but I will set those up once ready to package the app. The problem is that the program halts with no error message, so I don't even know what to look for. If I use the alternate syntax for the current print module (arguments added as separate strings), I get a "File Not Found" error, and that's it. I am open to a completely different approach to printing, if that has a better chance of working.

Code follows:

```
#Save and Print
def SavePrint ():

    # Create Word Document
    CliNameVar = CliName.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
    AppDateVar=AppDate.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
    RepBodyVar=RepBody.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
    from docx import Document
    from docx.shared import Pt
    from docx.shared import Inches
    CliDoc = Document ()
    body_style = CliDoc.styles['Body Text']
    body = CliDoc.add_paragraph(style=body_style).add_run(f'{CliNameVar} - {AppDateVar}')
    body.font.name = 'Arial'
    body.font.size = Pt(12)
    body = CliDoc.add_paragraph
    body = CliDoc.add_paragraph(style=body_style).add_run(f'{RepBodyVar}')
    CliDoc.add_picture('D:/Documents/DavidSignatureBlue.png', width=Inches(2.5))
    
    #Save 
    FileLoc=Path("C:/Claire's Documents/AAAAFidler/Clients/%s" % CliNameVar)
    FileName="C:/Claire's Documents/AAAAFidler/Clients/%s/%s - %s.docx" %(CliNameVar, CliNameVar, AppDateVar)
    FileLoc.mkdir(parents=True)
    CliDoc.save(FileName)
    
    #Print
    import subprocess
    subprocess.Popen("'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\winword.exe' '%s' /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit", shell=True).communicate() %FileName
```

UPDATE:
So, after wrestling with the fact that I can't seem to pass variables to the subprocess module, I tried using a TEMP folder, and hard-code the print filename. I got a bit further, in that Word opens (though I would prefer it happen in the background), but it still complains that the file name is not valid - even though I can see that the file exists.

```
#Print
import time
import shutil
import subprocess
tmpdir = "C:/Claire's Documents/TMPFILE"
os.mkdir(tmpdir)
tmpfil = "C:/Claire's Documents/TMPFILE/prntfile.docx"
shutil.copy(FileName, tmpfil)
time.sleep(3)
subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/root/Office16/winword.exe", "C:/Claire's Documents/TMPFILE/prntfile.docx", "/mFilePrintDefault", "/mFileExit"]).communicate()
time.sleep(5)
shutil.rmtree(tmpdir)
```

SECOND UPDATE:
Turns out, the subprocess module does not like spaces, even inside double quotes. Removed the space between "Claire's Documents", and now it prints - except it will not close again, per the "/mFileExit". Going to look at closing it as a separate instruction.

Comment: What exactly is your question now?

Comment: TL;DR: I couldn't make it print. 

I found the problem with the method I was using, but a new problem cropped up: once the file prints, it will not close the Word window.

I have been documenting the problem as it evolves, so that people will know where things currently stand.

Comment: Yes, but what is the question? What are others supposed to answer?

Comment: If you have already solved a part of the problem you could formulate that as a question and add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, as mentioned in my update, I found the problem to be twofold: The subprocess module does not like to have variables passed to it, and it doesn't like spaces in the path to the file it will be working on.

As such, the solution was to make a temporary file that always has the same name, and making sure that there were no spaces in the path to the temp file for the subprocess to get hung up on. I didn't even need the temp folder - just dropped the print file in the parent directory, and deleted it afterwards. It also turns out that the fact that the Word document opens in the foreground, and doesn't close is actually a feature, not a bug, so no further wrestling with this problem.

Code follows:

```
    #FileName variable set in Save section

    #Print
    import time
    import shutil
    import subprocess
    tmpfil = "C:/Claire'sDocuments/prntfile.docx"
    shutil.copy(FileName, tmpfil)
    time.sleep(3)
    subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office12/winword.exe", "C:/Claire'sDocuments/prntfile.docx", "/mFilePrintDefault"]).communicate()
    os.remove(tmpfil)
```